# CodeChef - Please like me

Tags: c, programming-challenge

> In a far away dystopian world, the measure of the quality of a person’s life is the numbers of likes he gets for an article about their life. For a person to stay alive, he has to acquire at least L number of likes before D days pass.
>
> People in this world employ various techniques to increase the number of likes. One of the famous ones is to dis-like and re-like their own article once per day. On doing so you can assume that the number of likes for the post increase by a constant factor C.
>
> So if one starts with S likes on Day-1, he would have D2 = S + C * S likes on Day-2, D3 = D2 + D2 * C on Day-3 etc. You are to answer if the person would survive at the end of Day-D or not.
>
> **Input**
>
> First line contains a single positive integer T denoting the number of test cases. The following T lines represent a test case each. Each test case contains 4 space-separated integers L, D, S and C.
>
> **Output**
>
> For each test case, print a single line containing “ALIVE AND KICKING” if the person would live, otherwise print, “DEAD AND ROTTING”.
>
> **Constraints**
>
> 1 <= T <= 1000
>
> 1 <= L <= 1000000000
>
> 1 <= D <= 1000000000
>
> 1 <= S <= 1000000000
>
> 1 <= C <= 1000000000
>
> **Sample cases**:
>
> **Input**
>
> 2
>
> 5 1 5 1
>
> 10 2 2 2
>
> **Output**
>
> ALIVE AND KICKING
>
> DEAD AND ROTTING

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        long long int l,d,s,c;
        scanf("%lld%lld%lld%lld",&l,&d,&s,&c);
        long long int i;
        long long int x=s;
        for(i=2;i<=d;i++)
            x*=(1+c);
        if(x>=l)
            printf("ALIVE AND KICKING\n");
        else
            printf("DEAD AND ROTTING\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I improve efficiency so that the time limit does not get exceeded?

Comment: Use the power operator: pow, from math.h. 5*5*5*5=pow(5,4). So (d-1) times (1+c) multiplied is: pow( (1+c),(d-1) ). I think you can work it out from here.

Comment: i made my own power function (refer to exponentiation by squares) but that gave me wrong answer

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101439/the-most-efficient-way-to-implement-an-integer-based-power-function-powint-int) for a reference implementation of an integer power function. Much faster than pow too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using a `power` function was that it returns a `floating` value. My variables are of type `int`. I changed them to `double` and used the `pow` function from `math.h` library and it worked.

I was also successful by using my own power function using the exponentiation by squares algorithm.

Here is my power function (using the exponentiation by squaring algorithm):

```
int power(int x, int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else if(n==1)
        return x;
    else if(n%2==0)
        return power(x*x,n/2);
    else if(n%2!=0)
        return x*power(x*x,(n-1)/2);
}
```

Comment: Great that you solved it. For completeness, could you add you implementation of the integer pow function in your answer?

Comment: @AtulShanbhag Since your function only operates on integers, so that's not a problem. Negative exponents don't really make sense for integer return values, since `x` can't take values in the range `]0,1[`, so for any negative exponent the result would be in this range as well. You might want to consider error handling, should someone provide a negative exponent or just change the parameter type to `unsigned int`.

Comment: In that case, I would simply change my function  and variable `x` from `int` type to `double` type. Then I would add an extra `if` statement that

    `if(n<0)
    return power(1/x,-n);`

Comment: Use bitwise operators to speed it up even more: n&1 to test uneven (logical AND); n<<1 for *2 (bitshift left) and n>>1 to /2 (bitshift right).

Comment: You need to handle overflow, otherwise your function could end up returning anything, including 0 or a negative number.

Comment: Change `(n-1)/2` to `n/2`.  The `-1` is not needed and removing it prevents the infinite loop then `n<0`.

Comment: All the `else` are not needed.  The last `if(n%2!=0)` is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

I think the key thing you are missing isn't a better `pow` function.  The problem is that you are iterating `d` times without checking whether you have surpassed `l`.  Notice that for the lowest `c` of 1, you are multiplying by 2 every loop.  The maximum `l` is 1000000000 which is less than 2^30.  Therefore the max number of loops you will ever need is 30.

If you simply checked every loop:

```
if (x >= l)
    break;
```

then you limit your loop to 30 iterations instead of 1000000000 iterations.